# Is XCode Menu Scripts not Relevant any more?

Tags: xcode

There was an article here:
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.01/2301XCode/index.html

But looking in Xcode folder, I see a startup script where it says:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# StartupScript
#
# This script is run at Xcode startup.
# This script is, however, no longer used to populate the User Scripts menu, as that is now done from within Xcode.
#
```

Does this mean it's not possible to customize xcode menu through scripts any more ? What's the substitute ?

Answer (score 0):

Aeons ago, user scripts menu were populated in this way. Now, there's a UI for it. It's the little script icon in between the "Window" and "Help" menus. Choose Edit User scripts from there to start your script management.

I think most of the other info in that article will still apply. In any case, the User Scripts functionality is now quite well documented at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/310-User_Scrips/user_scripts.html

It's said that in Xcode 4, the entire function is lost - which would be a shame.